# Как сделать круглую замыленную красивую тень со смещением?

Tags: android

Перепробовал через `drawable` (`stroke` и `gradient`), через код (рисовал на канвасе). Но я никак не могу получить нужную мне тень. Через `elevation` на Lolipop и выше получается красивая тень, но без смещения. `CardView` делает красивую тень, но в круглую тень он не умеет.

[image: нужная тень]

Comment: Свой фон картинкой?

Comment: Да, можно просто добавить эту картинку на фон. Но, во-первых, я хочу кодом, или хотя бы разметкой, а во-вторых, подогнать не так легко))